# Material-UI SimpleTable event handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am looking to obtain the rowData from an event triggered on the material-UI table component. The application I am building is very basic and thus needs just a basic table.

I have tried passing event handlers to numerous components (Table, TableCell, and TableRow) with no luck. In the past, it appears that the table component had a prop of onRowSelection, but that does not seem to be available anymore.

I am sure there is a very simple way to do this, and I have to be missing something extremely trivial, however, I have searched everywhere, and cannot find the basic solution and or methodology to make this happen.

```
let id = 0;
function createData(instrument, price, volume, rsi) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, instrument, price, volume, rsi };
}

const rows = [
  createData('TSLA', 283.65, 8.6, 13.2, 22),
  createData('AMZN', 1638.78, 9.0, 23, 46),
  createData('APPL', 172.91, 16.0, 24, 37),
  createData('AMRN', 21.36, 3.7, 67, 73),
  createData('PLUG', 1.71, 16.0, 49, 32),
];

class BasicTable extends React.Component {

render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table onRowSelection = {(event) => {console.log(event)}} className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell}>Instrument</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} align="right">Price</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} align="right">Volume</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableHeaderCell} align="right">RSI</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow selected={true} hover className={classes.tableRow}
                      key={row.id}>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableCell} component="th" scope="row">
                {row.instrument}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.price}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.volume}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.rsi}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
}

BasicTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(BasicTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write a onClick event and call the function like below

https://codesandbox.io/s/wwq0r9nn8?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, but how would I use this to actually obtain the row data? One would think that the MUI components would have a prop specifically for this. I am quite new to front end development and must be missing some basic knowledge. Is there anything you recommend I read that will help with this?

Comment: You can add a click eventlistner to the table rows and get the row data. Also you can read about material UI table APIs here https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/

Comment: Thank you so much. I truly appreciate your help.